# Catalogue of simple, illustrative game theory games

Tags: game-theory

Can anyone point me to a catalogue of well-known illustrative game theory models? I'm particularly interested in two-player competitive games.  I've searched a bit and found [this page](http://sage-doc.sis.uta.fi/reference/game_theory/sage/game_theory/catalog_normal_form_games.html) that lists normal-form games implemented in a particular package, which covers a lot of the very common ones (prisoner's dilemma, stag hunt, chicken).

I'd like to use these to build my game-theoretic intuition. And I'm interested in part because of a toy model I've been playing with; I'm curious if there's anything written up about it or about similar games, but I don't know what it would be called in the literature.

Comment: Steven Brams lists  all variations of 2x2 games in Superior Beings:  If They Exist, How Would We Know?  Game-Theoretic 
       Implications of Omniscience, Omnipotence, Immortality, and Incomprehensibility.  
       New York:  Springer-Verlag, 1983.  Rev. ed., 2007 (Springer).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of any discussions of simple NxN games? For example, one model I've been playing with is a zero-sum game where there are N "sites" to choose between, and player A has payoff v_i from going to site i if B chose a different site, and 0 otherwise.